# merging like objects and values with Array.reduce(}

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using vanilla js for this helper function inside of a react app / typescript.
Json data is fetched this holds every letter of the alphabet which is assigned a value and a key. These are layed out into a grid of tiles. When a user selects a tile, this is added to gameData array in React which is used for a list. If a user clicks onto the same tile this is merged so instead of multiple list elements with same values they are merged with quantity + quantity and value + value

The structure is as such

```
const apiData = [
  {key: 'A', value: 50, quantity: 1, color: '#3498db', ...etc},
  {key: 'B', value: 40, quantity: 1, color: '#e67e22', ...etc},
  ...
]

const gameData = [
 {key: 'A', value: 200, quantity: 4, color: '#3498db', ...etc},
 {key: 'E', value: 10, color: '#fa0', ...etc},
]

export function groupBy(array: GameData[]) {
  const group: GameData[] = Object.values(
    array.reduce((acc: any, { value, quantity, ...r }) => {
      const key = Object.entries(r).join("-");
      acc[key] = acc[key] || { ...r, quantity: 0, value: 0 };
      return ((acc[key].value += value), (acc[key].quantity += 1)), acc;
    }, {})
  );
  return group;
}
```

The reducer works and merges properly but I just feel like there must be a better way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: That looks just fine to me, linting aside. I'd prefer to use `for..of` [instead of reduce](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TnZ7jMFCa4Y), but using the same basic principle.

Comment: Do you want to game data to be grouped with the same and add the total value?

Comment: @AadilMehraj I edited it to show what the data looks like when merged with function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution seems ok, just a little hard to read. Here are my suggestions.

```
function groupBy(array){
    return Object.values(array.reduce((grouped, {value, quantity,...rest}) => {
        const key = Object.entries(rest).join('-');
        if(!grouped[key]){
            grouped[key] = {...rest, value: 0, quantity: 0};
        }
        grouped[key].quantity++;
        grouped[key].value += value;
        return grouped;
    },{}));
}
```

Or using a simple for:

```
function groupBy(array) {
    const grouped = {};
    for(let obj of array){
        const {value, quantity, ...rest} = obj;
        const key = Object.entries(rest).join('-');
        if(!grouped[key]){
            grouped[key]= {...rest, value: 0, quantity: 0};
        }
        grouped[key].quantity++;
        grouped[key].value+=value;
    }
    return Object.values(grouped);
}
```

Comment: Remember to use `const` when you aren't going to reassign - `let` is a *warning* to other readers of the code that you may reassign the identifier on the future

Answer (score 2):

You can clean your **groupBy** reduce function as follows:

```
function groupBy(data: GameData[]) {
    const result = data.reduce((total, item) => {
          const { key, value, quantity } =   item;
          const prevItem = total[key] || {};
          const {value: prevValue = 0, quantity: prevQuantity = 0} = prevItem;


          total[key]= {
                ...item,
                value: prevValue + value,
                quantity: prevQuantity + quantity,
          };

          return total;

    }, {});

    return Object.values(result);
}
```

For the given input it produces the folowing result:

```
const gameData = [
  {"key":"A","value":50,"quantity":1,"color":"#3498db"},
  {"key":"A","value":50,"quantity":1,"color":"#3498db"},
  {"key":"A","value":50,"quantity":1,"color":"#3498db"},
  {"key":"B","value":50,"quantity":1,"color":"#3498db"},
  {"key":"B","value":40,"quantity":1,"color":"#e67e22"}
];

const result = groupBy(gameData);
/*
result = [
  {"key":"A","value":150,"quantity":3,"color":"#3498db"},
  {"key":"B","value":90,"quantity":2,"color":"#e67e22"}
]
*/
```